# No error when creating a directory, but no directory was created

Tags: bash, hadoop

`start.sh` starts `copy_file.sh` and passes it 2 parameters

```
yeasterday_with_dash=2017-01-31
today_without_dash=20170201

echo "-----------RUN copy mta-------------"
bash copy_file.sh mta $today_without_dash
echo "-----------RUN copy rcr-------------"
bash copy_file.sh rcr $today_without_dash
echo "-----------RUN copy sub-------------"
bash copy_file.sh sub $today_without_dash
```

`copy_file.sh` is supoosed to check if a directory exists and if not create it.

```
hdfs_dir=/apps/hive/warehouse/mydb.db/fct_evkuzmin/${2}/file_${1}

if hadoop fs -test -d $hdfs_dir ; then
    echo "Directory "$hdfs_dir" exists"
else
    hadoop fs -mkdir $hdfs_dir
    echo "Creating "$hdfs_dir
fi
```

The script runs succesfully it seems.

The log.

```
yeasterday_with_dash=2017-01-31
today_without_dash=20170201
-----------RUN copy mta-------------
mkdir: `/apps/hive/warehouse/mydb.db/fct_evkuzmin/20170201/file_mta': No such file or directory
Creating /apps/hive/warehouse/mydb.db/fct_evkuzmin/20170201/file_mta
end copy mta files
-----------RUN copy rcr-------------
mkdir: `/apps/hive/warehouse/mydb.db/fct_evkuzmin/20170201/file_rcr': No such file or directory
Creating /apps/hive/warehouse/mydb.db/fct_evkuzmin/20170201/file_rcr
end copy rcr files
-----------RUN copy sub-------------
mkdir: `/apps/hive/warehouse/mydb.db/fct_evkuzmin/20170201/file_sub': No such file or directory
Creating /apps/hive/warehouse/mydb.db/fct_evkuzmin/20170201/file_sub
end copy sub files
```

But there is no actual directory created. What's the problem?

Comment: Can you double-quote it? `hadoop fs -mkdir "$hdfs_dir"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mkdir` with `-p` argument to also create parent directories.

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p etc
```